# How does these two ways of finding scalar (dot) product relate?

Tags: vectors

How does

```
a · b = a1b1 + a2b2 + a3b3
```

relate to

```
 → a ⋅ → b = || → a || ||→ b || cos θ
```

I don't know what to google to find this demonstration of how the two methods relate to eachother or imply eachother.

Comment: The cosine rule?

Comment: The angle between two vectors is defined using the second relation. That makes sense because those are equal in elementary geometry by the Cosine Rule.

Comment: "dot product cosine" at Google gives me as its first link, [Dot Product - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).  That article's section [Equivalence of the definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Equivalence_of_the_definitions) is responsive to your question.  I'd read starting from the top to ensure that you understand the notation being used.  (Also, link-only answers are not Answers, so this comment is not an Answer.)

Comment: Please learn the basics of formatting your questions!

Answer (score 4):

We want to show $$\vec u\cdot\vec v=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3.$$

Define $\vec{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)=u_1\hat i+u_2\hat j+u_3\hat k$ and $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)=v_1\hat i+v_2\hat j+v_3\hat k$, where $\hat i, \hat j$, and $\hat k$ are the unit vectors of the $x$, $y$, and $z$-axes.  Then we have
\begin{align}
\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}&=(u_1\hat i+u_2\hat j+u_3\hat k)\cdot(v_1\hat i+v_2\hat j+v_3\hat k)\\
&=\color{blue}{u_1v_1\hat i\cdot\hat i}+\color{red}{u_1v_2\hat i\cdot\hat j}+\color{red}{u_1v_3\hat i\cdot\hat k}\\
&\qquad+\color{red}{u_2v_1\hat j\cdot\hat i}+\color{blue}{u_2v_2\hat j\cdot\hat j}+\color{red}{u_2v_3\hat j\cdot\hat k}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\color{red}{u_3v_1\hat k\cdot\hat i}+\color{red}{u_3v_2\hat k\cdot\hat j}+\color{blue}{u_3v_3\hat k\cdot\hat k}\\
&=\color{blue}{u_1v_1}+\color{blue}{u_2v_2}+\color{blue}{u_3v_3}
\end{align}
as desired (since we have $\hat a\cdot\hat a=\vert\hat a\vert^2=1$ and perpendicular vectors have a dot product of $0$).

The geometric definition is a result of the Law of Cosines $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma.$$

Define $\vec w=\vec u-\vec v$ and let $\theta$ represent the angle between $\vec u$ and $\vec v$.  As such, we have \begin{align}
\vec w&=\vec u-\vec v\\
\vec w\cdot\vec w&=(\vec u-\vec v)\cdot(\vec u-\vec v)\\
\vert\vec w\vert^2&=\vec u\cdot\vec u-2\vec u\cdot\vec v+\vec v\cdot\vec v\\
\vert\vec w\vert^2&=\vert\vec u\vert^2+\vert\vec v\vert^2-2\vec u\cdot\vec v.
\end{align}

Matching the two equations, it follows that we can equate $$\vec u\cdot\vec v=\vert\vec u\vert\vert\vec v\vert\cos\theta.$$

Sometimes the algebraic and geometric definitions are used in conjunction to solve problems that involve variable and given vector components and angles between vectors.