# How does the second step come from the first step?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand how does the first step transform into the second:
[image]

I tried to apply the distributive property, but don't know how to proceed afterwards:
[image]

Comment: note that $a_1\vec i\cdot b_1\vec i=a_1b_1 \vec i\cdot \vec i$, etc.

Comment: and $\vec i\cdot\vec j=0$, for example, since $\vec i\perp\vec j$

Comment: I have something similar written up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499487/how-does-these-two-ways-of-finding-scalar-dot-product-relate/3499518#3499518).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hi, thanks for answering! I have never heard of this property. Could you tell me the name of it so I can search it up?

Comment: [linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Elementary_properties)